# How to change the target table of a SQL insert statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

How would you write a sql statement that allows you to insert data obtained from a form but will be entered in either one tabe or another depending on what is selected on the form?  I know how to insert the data from a form to a specified table but I need to be able to use the form to select which table the data will be entered into.  Here is a copy of my form...

```
print("<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Upload Your Motions and Orders Here</legend>
  <table width="80%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="label"> <label for="label">Select Your File:</label>    
    </p></td>
      <td class="input"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
      <input type="file" name="thefile" value="<? echo $thefile; ?>" accesskey="s" tabindex="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><span class="input">
        <label for="label">Type of File:</label>
      </span></td>
      <td class="input"><select name="field" id="field" value="<? echo $field; ?>" accesskey="t" tabindex="20">
        <option value="Motions">Motions</option>
        <option value="Orders">Orders</option>
        </select>      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="label">Name of File:</label> </td>
      <td class="input"><label for="type"></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>" accesskey="n" tabindex="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="label">Date Filed In Court:</label> </td>
      <td class="input"><label for="date"></label>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<? echo $date; ?>" accesskey="f" tabindex="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><span class="input">
        <label for="label">Description:</label>
      </span></td>
      <td class="input"><textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" value="<? echo $description; ?>" accesskey="d" tabindex="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="input"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload This File" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>");`
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Upload Your Motions and Orders Here</legend>
  <table width="80%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="label"> <label for="label">Select Your File:</label>    
    </p></td>
      <td class="input"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
      <input type="file" name="thefile" value="<? echo $thefile; ?>" accesskey="s" tabindex="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><span class="input">
        <label for="label">Type of File:</label>
      </span></td>
      <td class="input"><select name="field" id="field" value="<? echo $field; ?>" accesskey="t" tabindex="20">
        <option value="Motions">Motions</option>
        <option value="Orders">Orders</option>
        </select>      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="label">Name of File:</label> </td>
      <td class="input"><label for="type"></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>" accesskey="n" tabindex="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="label">Date Filed In Court:</label> </td>
      <td class="input"><label for="date"></label>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<? echo $date; ?>" accesskey="f" tabindex="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><span class="input">
        <label for="label">Description:</label>
      </span></td>
      <td class="input"><textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" value="<? echo $description; ?>" accesskey="d" tabindex="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="input"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload This File" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The type of file selection field will be what determines the table the data will be inserted into.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from running dynamic sql.  Since you have a list of know types, you can put the logic to choose a table in a case statement at the app layer based on the file type.  The other option is to create a stored procedure with a case statement, or a set of if statements.  This way you don't construct dynamic sql for the insert.